# Link of menu items

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu

It's me again, and I have the following issue:
Some menu items are redirecting to 404, but only when I access my website through a cellphone, and they don't redirect if I I'm on the homepage.
For instance, if I click on any sub menu item of Inscrições and then click on the menu item Inscrições again, it's going to redirect to 404.
I have no idea how to solve this problem, and it's really bugging because nowadays most people access the internet through their cellphones.

Comment: Is this on http://www.associacaoproesporte.org.br ?

Comment: Do you have different menus for your desktop / mobile? Can you reproduce this behavior with the "Inspect" function of Google Chrome in the Mobile Phone mode?
Right click on your site, choose "Inspect", choose "Toggle device toolbar Ctrl+Shift+M"

Comment: I use a different theme for the mobile version, because a vertical layout hides this problem, as the person wouldn't have to mouse over a menu item, like in the desktop version.I tried the toggle device toolbar and the behavior is emulated perfectly in the simulation.

Comment: Yes, the website is associacaoproesporte.org.br.

Comment: Could anyone please help me out? I've been stuck with this issue for a long time now.